# How can I download Stock data on an hourly basis

Tags: r, analysis, stock, quantmod

I am trying to read hourly data for stocks into R. I am able to upload daily data, however, I am interested in hourly data. The code below uploads the daily data. Is there a way to do that?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("ABUS")
```

Comment: I think you have *upload* and *download* confused. Edited your question...

Comment: This [reference](https://www.quantmod.com/examples/data/) suggests you can use `to.monthly`?

Comment: @NelsonGon, Thanks. However, I tried the "to.hourly" command but it returns only daily data.

Comment: @mustafa I am not sure you can get hourly data without purchasing the data. I could be wrong

Comment: @neuron Do you know a website that I can buy the data from?